# Installation issue via Composer

Tags: xampp, composer-php, symfony4

I´m working on Windows 7 and I have 2 Xampp installations:

- One with PHP 5.6.24
- Another with PHP 7.2.2

I have tried starting each Xampp individually and `phpinfo()` gives me the correct PHP version, but if I do `php -v` I always get that the PHP version is 6.6.24

This is causing the installation issue that shows the following output:

> [InvalidArgumentException]  Could not find package symfony/skeleton
>   with stability stable in a version  installable using your PHP version
>   5.6.24.

Is there a way of indicating the OS which PHP version to use? I was thinking that perhaps using environment variables could be the solution.

Comment: Rather than edit the question to add the solution, post it as answer! [Answering your own question is not forbidden](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/250208/4733879), but [officially encouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). (there is even an option to answer the question directly at the [Ask a Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) page)

Comment: Please don't add texts like "Solved" to the title. Instead, mark the most helpful answer as accepted by clicking the checkmark below the downvote button.

Comment: @Veve you are right, its possible to have to different PHP versions and the system environment variable path must contain the version to be used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit by the OP to the question:

> It has been resolved by adding the php directory to system environment variable PATH.